# I need /testfor help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to test for an item frame with a tripwire hook named "Key2A" in it. (Version 1.12, on a server. the server shouldn't be messing with the command though.) I'm using the command:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item_Frame] {TileX:-510,TileY:77,TileZ:-201,Item:{id:tripwire_hook,tag:{display:{Name:"Key2A"}}}}
```

I receive the error:

```
[02:23:44] entity.ItemFrame.name did not match the required data structure
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. Can someone help me fix the command?

Answer (score 2):

When setting data, Minecraft can "fix" things like leaving out the `minecraft:` part of item IDs. When *testing* for data, this will not happen. Therefore, replace `id:tripwire_hook` with `id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook"`.

Comment: Is the selector good too?  I'm pretty sure that's case sensitive now, and it should be lower case, at least from what I'm seeing on the wiki.

Comment: I tested the fixed command.  It does work.  @MBraedley I tried it with the upper case selector and it still functions properly

Comment: @MBraedley It may become case-sensitive at some point in the future (say in 1.13, when many commands are supposed to become more case-sensitive), so changing it to `item_frame` is probably a good idea. For the moment it is not.